# Como deixar a tabela mais dinâmica?

Tags: javascript, html, table

Eu tenho que criar um joguinho.

É uma tabela com uma palavra. As letras da palavra estarão todas misturadas e o usuário tem que escrever a palavra corretamente clicando em cada letra antes do tempo terminar.

Estou com dificuldade de fazer com que todas as linhas da tabela com `id`, seja de clique.

```js
//CLICAR NA TABELA
//primeiro fazer uma função que tenha uma varia como parametro para receber o id da div 
//chamar no onclick cada div
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(id);
    });
});

//CONTAGEM REGRESSIVA
/*var count = new Number();
var count = 10;
function start(){ //responsavel em contar o count
    if ((count -1) >= 0) {
    }
}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"> <!-- caracter diferente-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo_jogo.css">

 <title>Adivinha a palavra</title>

</head>
<body>
 <input type="button" onclick='teste(this.value)'>

 <table border= "0">
  <tr>
   <td colspan="15">Dica:</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="area">
   <td> <div id="num1"></div> </td> <!--UM ID EM TODAS AS DIV'S-->
   <td> <div id="num2"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num3"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num4"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num5"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num6"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num7"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num8"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num9"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num10"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num11"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num12"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num13"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num14"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num15"></div> </td>
   <td class="tempo">Tempo</td>     <!-- AQUI SERÁ O CRONOMETRO-->
  </tr>

  <tr class="area">
   <td> <div id="num16"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num17"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num18"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num19"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num20"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num21"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num22"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num23"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num24"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num25"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num26"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num27"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num28"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num29"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num30"></div> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="area">
   <td> <div id="num31"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num32"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num33"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num34"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num35"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num36"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num37"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num38"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num39"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num40"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num41"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num42"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num43"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num44"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num45"></div> </td>
     <td class="iniciar"> <button >Iniciar</button></td> <!-- MELHORAR ESSE BOTÃO E O DE SAIR-->
  </tr>

  <tr class="area">
   <td> <div id="num46"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num47"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num48"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num49"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num50"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num51"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num52"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num53"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num54"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num55"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num56"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num57"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num58"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num59"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num60"></div> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="area">
   <td> <div id="num61"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num62"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num63"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num64"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num65"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num66"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num67"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num68"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num69"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num70"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num71"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num72"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num73"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num74"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num75"></div> </td>
   <td class="sair"><button>Sair</button></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="area">
   <td> <div id="num76"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num77"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num78"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num79"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num80"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num81"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num82"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num83"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num84"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num85"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num86"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num87"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num88"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num89"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num90"></div> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="area">
   <td> <div id="num91"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num92"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num93"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num94"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num95"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num96"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num97"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num98"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num99"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num100"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num101"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num102"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num103"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num104"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num105"></div> </td>
   <td rowspan="4" class="informacoes">Informações: 
   As Letras da palavras, estão embaralhada;
   Tem 40 segundos para escrever corretamente;
   O tempo acabou e não conseguiu escrever, perdeu;
   terminou antes do tempo, mas a palavra está errada, perdeu;</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="area_perigo">              <!--NÃO ESTOU CONSEGUINDO TROCAR A COR-->
   <td> <div id="num106"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num107"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num108"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num109"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num110"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num111"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num112"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num113"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num114"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num115"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num116"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num117"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num118"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num119"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num120"></div> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="area_perigo">
   <td> <div id="num121"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num122"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num123"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num124"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num125"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num126"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num127"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num128"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num129"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num130"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num131"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num132"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num133"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num134"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num135"></div> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="area_perigo">
   <td> <div id="num136"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num137"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num138"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num139"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num140"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num141"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num142"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num143"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num144"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num145"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num146"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num147"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num148"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num149"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num150"></div> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td colspan="10">Respostas: </td>
  </tr>
 </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer com que as divs dentro de cada TD da tabela sejam clicáveis utilizando o seletor `$('div[id^=num]', 'table')`. Irá buscar dentro de `table` todas as divs que possuem um `id` começando com `num`:

```js
//CLICAR NA TABELA
//primeiro fazer uma função que tenha uma varia como parametro para receber o id da div 
//chamar no onclick cada div
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div[id^=num]', 'table').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(id);
    });
});

//CONTAGEM REGRESSIVA
/*var count = new Number();
var count = 10;
function start(){ //responsavel em contar o count
    if ((count -1) >= 0) {
    }
}*/
```

```css
/* apenas para mostrar as divs */
div{
   background: red;
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"> <!-- caracter diferente-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo_jogo.css">

 <title>Adivinha a palavra</title>

</head>
<body>
 <input type="button" onclick='teste(this.value)'>

 <table border= "0">
  <tr>
   <td colspan="15">Dica:</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="area">
   <td> <div id="num1"></div> </td> <!--UM ID EM TODAS AS DIV'S-->
   <td> <div id="num2"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num3"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num4"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num5"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num6"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num7"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num8"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num9"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num10"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num11"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num12"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num13"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num14"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num15"></div> </td>
   <td class="tempo">Tempo</td>     <!-- AQUI SERÁ O CRONOMETRO-->
  </tr>

  <tr class="area">
   <td> <div id="num16"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num17"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num18"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num19"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num20"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num21"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num22"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num23"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num24"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num25"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num26"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num27"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num28"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num29"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num30"></div> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="area">
   <td> <div id="num31"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num32"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num33"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num34"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num35"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num36"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num37"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num38"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num39"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num40"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num41"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num42"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num43"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num44"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num45"></div> </td>
     <td class="iniciar"> <button >Iniciar</button></td> <!-- MELHORAR ESSE BOTÃO E O DE SAIR-->
  </tr>

  <tr class="area">
   <td> <div id="num46"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num47"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num48"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num49"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num50"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num51"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num52"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num53"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num54"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num55"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num56"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num57"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num58"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num59"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num60"></div> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="area">
   <td> <div id="num61"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num62"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num63"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num64"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num65"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num66"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num67"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num68"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num69"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num70"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num71"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num72"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num73"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num74"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num75"></div> </td>
   <td class="sair"><button>Sair</button></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="area">
   <td> <div id="num76"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num77"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num78"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num79"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num80"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num81"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num82"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num83"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num84"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num85"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num86"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num87"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num88"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num89"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num90"></div> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="area">
   <td> <div id="num91"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num92"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num93"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num94"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num95"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num96"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num97"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num98"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num99"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num100"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num101"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num102"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num103"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num104"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num105"></div> </td>
   <td rowspan="4" class="informacoes">Informações: 
   As Letras da palavras, estão embaralhada;
   Tem 40 segundos para escrever corretamente;
   O tempo acabou e não conseguiu escrever, perdeu;
   terminou antes do tempo, mas a palavra está errada, perdeu;</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="area_perigo">              <!--NÃO ESTOU CONSEGUINDO TROCAR A COR-->
   <td> <div id="num106"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num107"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num108"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num109"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num110"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num111"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num112"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num113"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num114"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num115"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num116"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num117"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num118"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num119"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num120"></div> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="area_perigo">
   <td> <div id="num121"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num122"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num123"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num124"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num125"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num126"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num127"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num128"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num129"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num130"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num131"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num132"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num133"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num134"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num135"></div> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="area_perigo">
   <td> <div id="num136"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num137"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num138"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num139"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num140"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num141"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num142"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num143"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num144"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num145"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num146"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num147"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num148"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num149"></div> </td>
   <td> <div id="num150"></div> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td colspan="10">Respostas: </td>
  </tr>
 </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigada! Deu certo o código!

Comment: Que bom que deu certo! Não deixe de marcar a resposta com ✔️. ObG!